# client host name being appended to client requests

Tags: angularjs, node.js, minifiedjs

I have the following configuration in my angular nodejs app minified javascript file

```
   // Constants
    .constant('config', {
        appName: 'My App',
        appVersion: 1.0,
        apiUrl: "someAPI"
});
```

But when the requests are made from this client as

```
http:/server-hosting-client/someAPI/api/ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not found)
```

I want the requests to be sent as

```
 http://someAPI/api/
```

Where is this appending its own host name from?

Here is an example client request

```
.controller('HeaderCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'config', function($scope, $http, $location, config) {    
    $scope.appName = config.appName;
    $scope.selected = undefined;
    $http.get(
       config.apiUrl+'/api/', {
            'withCredentials' : true
        }).success(function(data) {



        });
```

Note that I am running the app from the dist folder

```
/dist/ npm start
```

Comment: Does `config.apiUrl` include `http://`? You need to include the protocol or it will assume the current page hostname

Comment: Thats a good point, I am going to try that

Comment: Thank you!!! Do you want to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config.apiUrl` needs to include the protocol:

```
// Constants
.constant('config', {
   appName: 'My App',
   appVersion: 1.0,
   apiUrl: "http://someAPI"
});
```

Otherwise, the API url is assumed to be a sub-path of the current hostname.